# How to copy data from fixtures to tenant schema table in Django-tenants?

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-views

**Info:** I am using django-tenants. I want to copy data from fixtures file to tenant schema table while creating new tenant. django-celery is handling the task. I want to run `fixtures_data_load` function after new tenant has been created

I don't understand how can i do that!

```
app.task()
def fixtures_data_load(self):
    with open('fixtures/groups.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
        # Convert json string to python object
        data = json.loads(data_file.read())

    # Create model instances for each item
    for item in data:
        # create model instances...
        item = YourModel(*item)
        YourModel.objects.bulk_create(items)
```

fixtures.json

```
[
    {
        "model": "auth.group",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "name": "admin",
            "permissions": []
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "auth.group",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "name": "producer",
            "permissions": []
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "auth.group",
        "pk": 3,
        "fields": {
            "name": "copy editor",
            "permissions": []
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "auth.group",
        "pk": 4,
        "fields": {
            "name": "reporter",
            "permissions": []
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "auth.group",
        "pk": 5,
        "fields": {
            "name": "anchor",
            "permissions": []
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "auth.group",
        "pk": 6,
        "fields": {
            "name": "nle",
            "permissions": []
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "auth.group",
        "pk": 7,
        "fields": {
            "name": "ticker oprator",
            "permissions": []
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "auth.group",
        "pk": 8,
        "fields": {
            "name": "assignment editor",
            "permissions": []
        }
    }
]
```